# Deleting Files and directories on a Solid State Drive (fdisk, dd, rm)

Tags: unix, dd, rm, fdisk

I have been reading for a while on how `rm`, `fdisk` and `dd` work. I wasn't able to fully understand their source code however. Let's assume I would like to delete my /dev/nvme0n1p3 partition and the files within it which I mounted on `/mnt/to_remove`

Assume, I try these 3 commands below:

`rm -rf /mnt/to_remove`

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvme0n1p3`

`fdisk /dev/nvme0n1` -> `d` -> `3`

I know that the dd command above will write 0s to all the sectors within `/dev/nvme0n1p3`.
Just making sure I understand the `rm` and `fdisk`. Deleting using `fdisk` will remove the record of /dev/nvme0n1p3 from the partition table.
`rm` will remove the directory and file listings off that partition. Is this correct? In that case, the data is recoverable if I remove them using rm or fdisk?

Comment: About `fdisk`: see [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1446907/432690) and my answer there.

Comment: Thanks! This explains why fdisk works super fast. Is the gpt partition scheme written to sectors 0-5, and also at the end of the drive