# How can I change my partition type? From ext2 to exFAT (or ext4)

Tags: usb, partitioning, filesystems, google-chrome-os

I would like to convert a ext2 partition to exFAT or ext4, doesn't matter which, using the command line, preferably via `sudo parted`; how can I do this?

- I am running CloudReady Home Edition off a USB and have created a 32GB partition on it (using GNU `parted`) to store files, so I can also use the same USB as file storage, creating it with an ext2 file format system, which CloudReady cannot read
- I want to convert this to exFAT or ext4 so that both macOS and CloudReady can read the partition

Comment: "I created it using GNU parted, and it created it with the ext2 file format system" – IFAIK [`parted` does not create filesystems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/551030/108618). Partitions and filesystems are [not the same concept](https://superuser.com/a/1446923/432690). Did you use `mkfs`, `mkfs.ext2` or `mke2fs` to actually create a filesystem? It' possible there is no filesystem in the partition at all.

Comment: Just an FYI, exFAT should be avoided as it doesn't support ACLs, with ext3 generally preferred on USB drives being exclusively used on BSD/Linux, as it's a non-journalling filesystem, versus ext4 which is journaling. There's nothing wrong with ext4 on a USB drive, it simply means it will be written to more often than when using an ext3 filesystem - it's personal preference with no right or wrong way to do it, as it depends on how the individual rates the pros/cons _(unlike SSDs, USB drives generally don't support S.M.A.R.T, so there's no way to track the health of the flash storage)_

Comment: Hi, sorry it seemed that the problem was that a restart was needed. Sorry! I'll leave this here for people with the same problem.

Comment: Can anyone help with another problem I have? I want to be able to resize my STATE partition on my CloudReady USB. (the container for My Files, Crostini, and apps, etc.).

Comment: Please take our short [tour] to learn how the site works. Comments are not for answering, comments are not for asking other questions.