# Recover formatted HDD data to itself

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery, file-recovery

I did format my HDD and lose any data on it accidently.

This happened by to burn a small image to the external HDD by Win32DiskImage so I know that I lost some data but not all of them. Anyway I recover some files but I don't have enough space to recover and store all of them.

The HDD was a single partition and the image size was 150 MB.

Is there any way to recover data to HDD itself without lost more data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the single partition started after the first 150 MB of the entire drive then software like TestDisk will be able to recover the partition by adding it to the (or a new) partition table. This is because the image overwrote the old partition table, but it was not large enough to reach the filesystem (compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1446923/432690)). You won't need to recover files because the partition and the filesystem will be recovered in place. *But only in case the image was not large enough to reach the filesystem.*

---

I'm almost certain the only partition started earlier, the common offset from the beginning of the disk is 1 MiB. In such case the image overwrote the beginning of the filesystem and you cannot recover data to the HDD itself without risk of losing more data.

Follow this answer: [*How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?*](https://superuser.com/a/987169/432690) Save recovered data to elsewhere.

If you are totally without "elsewhere", you can create a partition substantially smaller than the disk, starting at any possible offset, then scan the remaining fragment(s) of the disk e.g. with PhotoRec. You will possibly be able to recover some (parts of) files from the remaining fragment(s) and store them in the new filesystem, but (parts of) files that used to be where the new filesystem is will be lost for sure. It's a lottery which (parts of) files you will lose. And you obviously cannot store more than the new filesystem size. The bigger the new filesystem, the more you can lose; the smaller the new filesystem, the less you can save. You can repeat the process though, but I guess you don't want to end up with multiple filesystems.

To semi-maximize your chances you could try to find a reasonably large fragment of the disk filled with zeros (but it's unlikely you'll find it) or a part from which recovery software can recover nothing valuable; and create a partition there.

To really maximize your chances get another disk.