# How to merge unallocated space to a partition in linux using the terminal

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, terminal

I am running a linux server on one of my machines and I recently upgraded the boot drive to a larger capacity drive. I used *dd* to clone my older boot drive but now my new boot drive has the same size showing up as my old drive, so how do I merge the unallocated space to my new drive partition using the terminal as I have no GUI.

Edit: This is my current display of the server and `fdisk - l`:

[image: Server info]

[image: fdisk - l output]
[image: lsblk output]

The output of `mount | grep /dev/sda2` is:

```
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw, relatime)
```

[image: mount | grep /dev/sda2]

Comment: What is the output of `lsblk`? What is the output of `fdisk -l`? (use `sudo` if needed). Please [edit] and add this information to the question. Tell us what device the question is about and what exactly you want to do with the unallocated space (i.e. which partition you want to expand, if this is what you want to do).

Comment: Not having a GUI isn't an issue because you can't manage partitions anyway within a running system. Knowing that you can boot a desktop Linux live session and use any of the standard graphical tools for that.

Comment: @ChanganAuto "you can't manage partitions anyway within a running system" – Depending on what partition(s) are to change, filesystem(s) therein and operations to perform, this statement may *or may not* be true.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Indeed, but the assumption here is the OP wants to expand "/" and they may or may not even have a `swap` or other partition after it, with the unallocated space all at the end of drive, resulting from the cloning.

Comment: @ChanganAuto "May or may not" is the key. For now we know very little about the current setup and what the OP wants to do. Your assumption regarding `/` is a guess. Therefore IMO the definitive statement "you can't manage partitions anyway within a running system" is too strong. "You may or may not be able to manage …" is what I agree.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm sure my guess will be correct in the end. If not I'll buy you dinner at the Jamie Oliver's restaurant of your convenience :)

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618). Post text. If you think an image of text is for some reason better than text, post the image along the text, not instead of the text.

Comment: If `/dev/sda` is the disk in question then what `fdisk -l /dev/sda` prints is the most important part of the output of `fdisk -l` (frankly: the only important part; I asked for the output of `fdisk -l`, not `fdisk -l /dev/sda`, because you hadn't told us the name of the disk). In the picture you posted this crucial part is truncated.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I have edited the post with additional information regarding `fdisk -l`. Also I would prefer adding the unallocated space to `/` but if it is not possible then a new partition would work as well.

Comment: Again: what is the output of `lsblk`? It's better to post it as text.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski there is only 1 disk in my system right now, which sda. It only has 1 partition as well. I have attached the updated picture of `lsblk` as well now

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. What is the output of `mount | grep /dev/sda2`? [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski `/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw, relatime) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup seems very simple. The relevant partition is `/dev/sda2`, it contains `ext4` filesystem, the filesystem is mounted as `/`. The free space is adjacent to the partition, after the partition (i.e. "to the right").

You want to expand the partition and the filesystem to the right. As `ext4` can be expanded to the right online (i.e. when mounted), you can do all this from within the running system. No reboot required.

Please read the entire answer before proceeding.

To be on the safe side, invoke `sudo blkid /dev/sda2` and save its output. We will need the string in double-quotes just after `PARTUUID=`.

Expand the partition:

1. Run `sudo fdisk /dev/sda`.
2. Delete (`d`) the partition number 2.
3. Create anew (`n`) a partition number 2. The start sector must be what it was (`4096`). Accept the default end sector, it will be somewhat lower than `1953525167`. The type of the partition by default should be `Linux filesystem` and this is right.
4. After seeing `Created a new partition`, examine it (`p`). You should see `/dev/sda2` with the size of about `931.5G` and the type `Linux filesystem`. `/dev/sda1` should be unaffected (i.e. exactly as it was).
5. To be on the safe side, change partition UUID for the second partition (`x`, then `u`). Type the exact string you got in the output of `blkid /dev/sda` after `PARTUUID=` (type the string without double-quotes). Return to the main menu (`r`).
6. In case of any doubt quit without writing (`q`) and wait until you get further help. But if everything looks like I described, write the modified partition table to the disk (`w`).

Yes, [deleting a partition and creating it anew is the right way](https://superuser.com/a/1446923/432690). Now it's time to expand the filesystem.

Expand the filesystem:

1. Run `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda2`. By default the tool will expand the filesystem so it takes the entire (new) partition.
2. Verify with `df -h` the filesystem is as large as you expected and there is free space in it.

The filesystem is still the old filesystem with its old `UUID`. We took care to replicate the `PARTUUID` of the old partition to the new one. Regardless if your GRUB and `/etc/fstab` use one or the other, they shouldn't notice the difference and the OS should still be able to boot.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. It now shows 931.5gb for the partition `/dev/sda2`

Comment: @AliAsgharChakera The first version of this answer didn't care about `PARTUUID`. If you followed it then please see if your `/etc/fstab` contains `UUID=` in the entry where the second field is `/`. If it does then your GRUB probably also uses `UUID` and it's safe to reboot. If your `fstab` uses `PARTUUID=` then don't reboot, we need to investigate further to avoid possible mishap. Sorry for this.

Comment: Sorry for being too dumb but I am not sure how to read `etc/fstab`, I used `cat` but it is saying something about `blkid` but `blkid /etc/fstab` is not showing anything.

Comment: This is output I am getting on `cat` `# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/77e0f9ea-8ca8-42ae-9800-e795f3a2b438 / ext4 defaults 0 1/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0`

Comment: @AliAsgharChakera OK, `/dev/disk/by-uuid` in `fstab` is fine. `by-partuuid` would be unfortunate for us. My answer is now improved but I think you don't need to do anything more, your OS should reboot fine.

Comment: Ok, great. Thank you so much for your help.