How to Merge 2 Unallocated Spaces that are on either side of Primary Partition? (New Linux/Ubuntu User)
Current Disk Setup
Please see image link: I have unallocated spaces to left and right of my primary partition (that has the Linux File System and EFI). Have installed GParted but need help on how can I merge in either of the following manners:

merge the unallocated spaces and move it to the extreme right. And how to make this as a new partition altogether that is separate from system files/drive.

I have recently shifted from Windows to Linux, so any detailed step-wise guidance would be helpful. Essentially I want to keep the System Files separate (like Windows C Drive) and combine the unallocated spaces as a new partition (like a D Drive of Windows).

if the above is not possible then how can merge both of the unallocated or at least the left side unallocated space with system file partition?

Additional Questions:
A) How much space does the Linux system file need? So that I can leave that much and create new partition in future.
B) In my search for these answers, I have seen there is also a Linux Swap tag which is missing from my current setup? What is that and is it something mandatory to have?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.


It is not worth the trouble to use the 660 MB unallocated space. Moving it requires moving all other partitions, a process prone to error and preventing rebooting. It is tiny.
It is easy to merge the ext4 Linux partition with the unallocated space, and that has already been answered: https://superuser.com/questions/1745799/how-to-merge-unallocated-space-to-a-partition-in-linux-using-the-terminal

